# C printf char more than or equal to 8 character in a row manner

Tags: c, char

```
if (namelist==NULL)
{
   namelist=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char**));
   namelist[i]=name;
}
else
{
   namelist=(char**)realloc(namelist,(i+1)*sizeof(char**));
   namelist[i]=name;
}

for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
   printf("%s\t\t%s\n",namelist[i],namelist[i]);
}
```

The problem is if I enter `"abcdefg"`, `"abcdefgh"` and `"abc"` as input, I will get

```
abcdefg          abcdefg
abcdefgh                    abcdefgh
abc              abc
```

Is there any way to get the second `"abcdefgh"` to get in line as the second `"abcdefg"` and `"abc"`?

Answer (score 8):

stop using TAB characters (\t) as separators, use proper format specifications instead, if you want your strings to start at 20th column, write:

```
printf( "%-20s%s", namelist[i],namelist[i]);
```

Comment: @Jack the number after the percent sign tells the format width, and minus sign controls left/right alignment, try a few variants and see how it works -- the easiest way to learn, imho

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
printf("%-20s%-20s\n",namelist[i],namelist[i]);
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) for more info about `printf`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider you're welcome! also, second "-20" argumens seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

To stay flexible you might want to use parameterized widths:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum Alignment_e
{
  alignmentUndefined = -1,
  alignmentLeft = 0,
  alignmentRight,
  alignmentMax
} Alignment_t;

typedef struct Tab_s
{
  int position;
  Alignment_t alignment;
} Tab_t;

#define FORMAT_TABBED_STRING "%*s"
#define TABBED_STRING( \
  str, \
  tab \
) \
  ((tab).alignment != alignmentLeft) ?(tab).position :-(tab).position, (str)


/* test */
int main()
{
  const Tab_t tabs[] = {
    {9, alignmentLeft},
    {32, alignmentRight},
    {-1, alignmentUndefined} /* array termination; not to be used as tab descriptor */
  }; 

  char s1[] = "s1";
  char s2[] = "s2";

  printf(FORMAT_TABBED_STRING"|"FORMAT_TABBED_STRING"|\n", TABBED_STRING(s1, tabs[0]), TABBED_STRING(s2, tabs[1]));
  printf(FORMAT_TABBED_STRING""FORMAT_TABBED_STRING"\n", TABBED_STRING(s1, tabs[1]), TABBED_STRING(s2, tabs[0]));  
}
```